# How to manage monthly customer activities?

Tags: process, tools, terminology

Suppose you allocate to your customers 3 of Activity A/month and 5 of Activity B/month.  How do you keep track of what you've allocated and what they've used every month?

Something that is going to show me this on the first of the month:

```
                   Activity A          Activity B
Customer Lily          3                  0
Customer Chuck         3                  5
Customer Francis       3                  5
```

and this in the middle of the month, etc:

```
                Activity A          Activity B
Customer Lily          3                  5
Customer Chuck         1                  4
Customer Francis       1                  2
```

So I know what they've used and how many are remaining.

What is the terminology used to describe this "activity tracking"?  What best-practices are recommended for doing this efficiently?

Comment: how's that? a bit open-ended, but maybe it fits the bill?

Comment: I don't agree this is a software recommendation question- however it is not a project management question either and is therefore out of scope on PM:SE. It is hard to see how any answer to this would be better than: "Manually keep track of what customers have used by keeping notes, possibly in paper files or in a spreadsheet". But that is nothing to do with Project Management...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about order tracking not Project Management

Comment: What are these "activities?" Is it resources on a project, tasks in a process, or what? Even with the edits, I'm not sure how this relates to project management.

Comment: On a separate note, you get brownie points for engaging the community and trying to improve the question. Whether it's closed or not, I hope you continue to find PMSE a valuable resource.

Comment: Suppose you have 5000 hundred customers.  Some are entitled to 5 widgets/month, some are entitled to 10 widget/month, some are entitled to 100 widgets/month.  How do you track usage per customer per month?  Manual notes? Excel spreadsheet? Write my own program/database?  If not project management, then what is it?  Thank you in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction.  Or just ignore and close as off-topic. Toodles....

Comment: There isn't enough context to adequately answer this question. How are widgets allocated? How do you know who has and hasn't used a widget? Is the system that notifies you automatic? If so, then yes you write a program and you'll probably need a database. If not then you're pretty much hosed with 5000 hundred customers...

Comment: You're probably looking for CRM or ERP software, or some other sort of supply chain system. Unfortunately, I can't conceive of this as a project management issue.

Comment: Maybe you could give it a try @ [Product Management SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62137/product-management).

Comment: Just wondering, if we see this question from a maintenance project / service operation point of view, couldn't we consider the given activities as areas of support?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE!  This strikes me as being about budget control. You have an estimated budget of giving each client 3A's and 4B's per month where A's and B's are buckets of hours. If so, this would fall under estimated vs actual time tracking or activity based accounting. Is this line of thinking on track?

Comment: Perhaps this is an accounting question? See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60707/accounting.

Comment: I went ahead and cleared this from the close review queue; however, if anyone has a strong case for this not fitting our site's scope, please start a [meta] discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to PMSE!  Focusing on your question:

> What is the terminology used to describe this "activity tracking"?
>   What best-practices are recommended for doing this efficiently?

I strongly believe all terminologies and best-practices you need will be answered by **[ITIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library)**, as ITIL is a set of practices / best practices to make IT services fit business needs.

On your specific question, you might want to check the **[ITIL Service Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library#Service_operation)** process, as your project is already built and being maintained. There are plenty of softwares out there to help tracking requests, but, as mentioned before, PMSE isn't the right place for software recommendations.

Regarding how to make such activities more *efficient*, you can also check out the **[ITIL Continuous Service Improvement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library#Continual_service_improvement_.28CSI.29)** process.

Hope this helps.  Success!